# Django tabularInline 'categories.Category_children_ids' has more than one ForeignKey to 'categories.Category'. You must specify a 'fk_name' attribute

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin, many-to-many

I'm want to create nested categories, model work fine.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    children_ids = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Category", blank=True, related_name="categories"
    )
    ...etc
```

but, when i add inline for admin panel

```
class ChildrensInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Category.children_ids.through
```

compiler shows me error:
'categories.Category_children_ids' has more than one ForeignKey to 'categories.Category'. You must specify a 'fk_name' attribute.

I also try fk_name='categories', and columns name inside Category_children_ids table, but it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `fk_name` has to be the name of the class (lower-case), prefixed with either `"from_"` or `"to_"`, depending on your needs. So in your case, it has to be either `fk_name='from_category'` or `fk_name='to_category'`:

```
class ChildrensInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Category.children_ids.through
    fk_name='from_category' # or: 'to_category'
```

Generally, a quick way to figure such things out is to (transiently) place a simple `print(model.__dict__)` pretty much anywhere in your code, here e.g. right after the second line. Then all fields of `model` will be shown in the console output.